# How to save a very long integer data in the MYSQL Data base

Tags: python, mysql, encryption

I used an encryption algorithm with 265(or more) bit keys and try to save the encrypted data to a database, my encrypted data is a very big integer. I have a problem when trying to save it in the MYSQL database server. the data is saved in the database fields as continuous of '9'.Note that the types of all fields in my database are VARCHAR(), this is the code of determining fields type"

```
     DB_Columns="(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,CredtNo VARCHAR(700),Fname VARCHAR(700), Lname VARCHAR(700),  Balance VARCHAR(1000) )"
```

and the statement of inserting the encryptied data using python is:

```
    insert_stmt = (f"INSERT INTO {Tname} (PhoneNo,CryptoPhon, Fname, Lname, Balance ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

    Cursor.execute(insert_stmt, Record)  # Executing the SQL command
```

Note that, the record is my encrypted data, and one of the value to be saved in my database is :
(2175317202645953348971113133719362660225751942313095427832814482408365145539992811710213981089606200860357565008258095906567757394686551412950904123490993298692780332626039419440732654731110306170537866185857978741870335596755093012097029150 )of type integer

Now when I want to retrieve my encrypted data from the database it will be like this:
'9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.........99'

Can I know what is the problem, and how to solve it?

Comment: What is the error? What is the code that creates the Record parameter? Likely that something is going wrong when MySQL is trying to convert the elements of Record into strings.

Comment: Binary data should be `VARBINARY`, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I saved the encrypted data in the database as an integer number, not a binary value, do you think the conversion to binary solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with MySQL but maybe you could use
`VARBINARY` or a BLOB like data type.